# Is there a way to not have to repeat this function invocation in pattern matching?

Tags: f#

I have a string for which I want to use an active pattern to match against. 
I've noticed I have to repeat the same function invocation when the value is an input to a function. Is there a way to not have to keep calling the function?

```
let (|A|B|C|X|) stringValue =
        match stringValue with
        | value when compareCaseInsensitive stringValue "a" -> A
        | value when compareCaseInsensitive stringValue "b" -> B
        | value when compareCaseInsensitive stringValue "c" -> C
        | _ -> X stringValue
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could define yet another active pattern for your *black-box* function:

```
let (|CCI|_|) (v: string) c =
    if v.Equals(c, System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) then Some()
    else None

let (|A|B|C|X|) stringValue =
        match stringValue with
        | CCI "a" -> A
        | CCI "b" -> B
        | CCI "c" -> C
        | _ -> X stringValue
```

Comment: Active patterns all the way down!

Comment: @mydogisbox Yes, as opposed to your answer:-)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. While you do have to repeat CCI, one of the hidden benefits here is that the partial active pattern allows me to use it again in downstream branching without having to redefine the variable.

Answer (score 5):

It appears you're trying to force pattern matching where it isn't necessarily the best fit.  A good indicator that you're trying to force pattern matching is a lot of conditional checks in your pattern match (in this case you're not actually doing any pattern matching!).

```fs
let (|A|B|C|X|) stringValue =
        let compareValue = compareCaseInsensitive stringValue
        if compareValue "a" then A
        elif compareValue "b" then B
        elif compareValue "c" then C
        else X stringValue
```

Comment: The complexity I didn't include in the example is that the active pattern is  really a string field check on a C# class so I can then apply pattern matching to the class. The class is passed around for computations. Since there's no inheritance structure a discriminated union doesn't really apply to the class.

Comment: @moarboilerplate I'm not sure what you mean.  Where am I using a discriminated union?  The change I made was to partially apply the function and then use if checks instead of pattern matching.

Comment: I was just mentioning that I wouldn't be able to use a discriminated union as an alternative if I was to try and change up the approach. Once the class gets involved I am not sure if I am trying to force pattern matching at that point because I don't see very viable alternatives (other than straight-up conditionals, of course)

Comment: Sometimes conditionals are the right path.  Only pattern match when you're branching on the structure of the data rather than a property of the data.  @markseemann gives a potentially nice way of working around that for more complicated cases.

Comment: if I replace with conditionals lint tells me to consider pattern matching.

Comment: I haven't used the linter, but I think its new and could probably use some tweaking.

Answer (score 5):

For the problem as given, I'd go with the answer suggested by *mydogisbox*, but in case this question is a stand-in for a more complex real problem, or there's some other reason that you *must* use pattern matching, you can do something like this:

```
let (|A|B|C|X|) stringValue =
    let compare x = compareCaseInsensitive stringValue x
    match List.map compare ["a"; "b"; "c"] with
    | [true; _; _] -> A
    | [_; true; _] -> B
    | [_; _; true] -> C
    | _ -> X stringValue
```

This is definitely **not a technique I'd use in the case of the question as posted**, but perhaps it can inspire a solution if there's a more complicated underlying problem.

Comment: Luckily my solution did not require this level of complexity but helpful to keep in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
let (|A|B|C|X|) (stringValue: string) =
        match stringValue.ToLower() with // or your custom toLowerCase function
        | "a" -> A
        | "b" -> B
        | "c" -> C
        | _ -> X stringValue
```

Comment: I considered this solution as well, but decided to treat `compareCaseInsensitive` as a black box.